# php5 is already the newest version but in phpinfo i get 5.4

Tags: 12.04, php, ppa

Details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

I want to install php5.5 so i try next step:

```
php -v

PHP 5.4.26 (cli) (built: Apr  8 2014 10:05:18)

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

php5 is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

When i use command:

```
sudo apt-cache policy php5
```

I get next:

```
php5:
  Installed: 5.5.29+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+3
  Candidate: 5.5.29+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+3
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.29+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+3 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.3.10-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

But in my **phpinfo()** and **php -v** i see version 5.4. How i can switch version to 5.5 ? What i need to do? I try reboot server but nothing has changed.

---

```
locate bin/php

/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php
/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php-cgi
/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php-cgi.bin
/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php-config
/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php.bin
/opt/bitnami/php/bin/phpize
/opt/bitnami/php/sbin/php-fpm
/usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php-cgi
/usr/bin/php-config
/usr/bin/php-config5
/usr/bin/php5
/usr/bin/php5-cgi
/usr/bin/phpize
/usr/bin/phpize5
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5
/usr/sbin/php5-fpm
/usr/sbin/php5dismod
/usr/sbin/php5enmod
/usr/sbin/php5query
```

Comment: Are you using php-fpm or the apache module?

Comment: @Ravan in phpinfo i see next line `Server API : FPM/FastCGI`

Comment: Just a steps correction, Would you follow this:
`sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
&& sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
&& sudo apt-get update
&& sudo apt-get install -y php5` Then confirm the vestion with `php5 -v`

Comment: edit your question and add output of `locate bin/php`

Comment: @Ravan i add into question this part please answer what i need do?

Comment: Which PHP SAPI did you install from the PPA? `php5-cli`, `php5-fpm`, `libapache2-mod-php5` or another?

Comment: @muru i install by next line `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5` and than `sudo apt-get install php5`, or what command i need to show you?

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you are having php installed in two locations. You can check that with `locate php` and with `which php` you will know actually what path your current shell using.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done` so i see problem in Apache, maybe need change php.ini to get new version.

Comment: can you provide output for `which php` and `updatedb && locate php`

Comment: `which php` - `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php`, `locate php` show many path, i write main:
`/opt/bitnami/php/..`
`/usr/bin/...`
`/usr/include/php5/...`
`/usr/share/php/...`
`/usr/share/php5/...`
`/var/lib/php5/...`

Comment: Okay I got your issue. Actually you are using bitnami which has php version `5.4`  and your php package installed with `apt-get` is  with version 5.5.
So solution is either you remove bitnami or upate your `PATH` variable so that it uses php installed with `apt-get`.

Comment: where i can find `PATH` to change it?

Comment: you can check your path with command `echo $PATH`. and you will be able to update it in your `/etc/bashrc`  so that it will be overridden for all users.

Comment: I run this command and get next value `/opt/bitnami/varnish/bin:
/opt/bitnami/sqlite/bin:
/opt/bitnami/php/bin:
/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin:
/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:
/opt/bitnami/common/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games
`. In file .bashrc i see that path inline `PATH="/opt/bitnami/varnish/bin:/opt/bitnami/sqlite/bin:/opt/bitnami/php/bin:/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:$PATH"`. What i need change in this line? Please help, thank you!

Comment: Please remove php path `/opt/bitnami/php/bin` from .bashrc file

Comment: i delete this line and reboot server. Now i see version 5.5 if in terminal i use `php -v`, but if i use `phpinfo()` i see old version 5.4. http://screencast.com/t/phXkYzUbs4 
http://screencast.com/t/D2as8lyqnMsc

Comment: Maybe i need change settings in Apache, which need to load new version of php, but i can't find this line in `httpd.conf` ( `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf `)